# Showing the equivalence of two statements regarding the one-sided limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have the following definition for the right limit

> If $a$ is a right accumulation point for $D$, we say that $L$ is the limit of $f$ from
> right at $a$, denoted by $\lim\limits_{x\to a+} f(x) = L$,if for any neighbourhood $U \in V(L)$ there exists $r > 0$
> such that $f((a, a + r) \cap D) \subseteq U$.

and I need to show the equivalence of the following two statements

> $(i)\lim\limits_{x\to a+} f(x) = L$
>
> $(ii)$ For any sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $a_n \in D$ and $a_n > a$ for all $n \in N$ such that
> $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} a_n = a$ we have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(a_n) = L.$

In the question, $L$ was an extended real number, but currently I am trying to show this only for $L\in\mathbb R$. So far, I was able to show that $(i)$ implies $(ii)$ but I am stuck with the other implication.

**My proof so far for $(ii) \implies (i)$:**

To show that $(i)$ holds, I am using the above definition of right limit. Take any neighbourhood $U \in V(L)$, then $(L-r,L+r) \subseteq U$ for some $r>0$. I want to show that $f((a,a+r)\cap D) \subseteq U$ holds exactly for that $r$ that we got from $U$. It is sufficient to show $f((a,a+r)\cap D) \subseteq (L-r, L+r)$.

At that point I am trying to make a transition to sequences to use $(ii)$ but I have no idea how to. If I were to have a sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} a_n = a$ and with elements $a_n \in ((a,a+r)\cap D)$, it would mean that $a_n>a$ and $a_n \in D$ so it would be perfect for using $(ii)$. But I don't know if I have such a sequence or not.

Can you help please give me ideas on how to proceed on my proof or give me another starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

You want to prove that
$$(\forall U\in V(L))\; (\exists r>0) \;:$$
$$\;f((a,a+r)\cap D)\subset U$$

assume the negation,

$$(\exists U\in V(L))\; : \;(\forall r>0)$$$$\; \exists x\in(a,a+r)\cap D \;: f(x)\notin U$$

Take $ r=\frac 1n $  and $ x $ will be $ x_n$ satisfying $$a<x_n<a+\frac 1n$$